# How could I make this work with UIScrollView?

Tags: ios, ipad, loops, sdk, uiscrollview

I'm inserting dynamically anywhere from 1 to 300 buttons inside a UIScrollView(as subviews). Currently, the buttons line up nicely but is not scrolling as I'd like them to. It just scrolls horizontally without a paging effect. Ideally, they way I'd like it to work is:

- Display a max of 48 buttons per "page"
- When scrolling to the right, show next "page" with 48 additional buttons

My code:

```
-(void)populateScrollView:(NSMutableArray *)colors {
// Properties
NSInteger count = 0;
NSInteger rowsize = 48;
CGFloat pageNum = 6;
CGFloat pageWidth = scrollView.frame.size.width;
CGFloat pageHeight = scrollView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat visibleWidth = 465;

myButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Clear the subviews if any
for (UIView *subview in scrollView.subviews) {
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
}

for (Color *element in colors) {
    // Set the button properties    
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"color_overlay.png"];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    div_t temp = div(count, rowsize);
    button.frame = CGRectMake(52 * temp.rem , 52*temp.quot, 52, 52);
    button.tag = count++;
    UIImage *effect = [UIImage imageNamed:element.image_resource];
    effectImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:effect]; 
    effectImage.frame = CGRectMake(52 * temp.rem , 52*temp.quot, 52, 52);

    // Color the graphic if color available. If not, load the image
    unsigned result = 0;
    if ([element.hex_value length] > 1){
        NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:element.hex_value];
        [scanner scanHexInt:&result];
        button.backgroundColor = UIColorFromRGB(result);
    }
    else {
        effectImage.image = effect;
    }
    // Set actions for the color
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(changeGraphicColor:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [myButtons addObject:button];

    for (UIButton *myButton in myButtons){
        [scrollView insertSubview:effectImage atIndex:1];
        [scrollView insertSubview:myButton atIndex:2];   
    }
}
// Set scrollView contentSize and create pages:
CGFloat leftShift=floor(((visibleWidth-pageWidth)/2)/pageWidth)*pageWidth;
CGFloat contentSizeReduction=2*leftShift;

scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageNum*pageWidth-contentSizeReduction,pageHeight);

[myButtons removeAllObjects];
[myButtons release];
```

}

I'm thinking the way I'm adding the buttons won't allow me to implement what I am trying to accomplish. What do you guys think I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you set scrollView.pagingEnabled to YES?

Comment: I am able to scroll through no problems, but it does not behave the way I want it to. Currently it scrolls from left to right, but it does not show 48 buttons at a time (what i mean by that is, if I scroll to the right, i should see a whole new set of 48 buttons)

Comment: I apologize Im just being dumb :( The pagingEnabled did it for me. Now I just need to adjust the dimensions so that the edges of the buttons do not show on new pages